# Mathematical notation to define tuples in a set with an alphabet

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I am a computer science student trying to wrap my head around some mathematical notation, so is there any elegant mathematical notation for the following:

I would like to define a $Set$, denoted $K^{n}$, such that the elements in the $Set$ are tuples, $a_{1}, ..., a_{n}$, where $a_{i} \in \{0, t, 1\}, 1 \le i \le n$. As shown by the example below:

Example:

$K^{3}$ = $\{<0,0,0>,<t,0,0>,<1,0,0>,<1,t,0>,... \}$

Also, are there any notation for describing multiple constraints of what kind of elements the $Set$ can contain?

Example:

Constraint 1: If $X \in K^{n}$, then $\exists!a_{i}=\{t\}, 1 \le i \le n$.
(There can only be one unique $\{t\}$ in $a_{1},...,a_{n}$)

$<0,t,t> \notin K_{3}$.

Apologize for my terrible notation.

Comment: Is t to appear no more than once or exactly once in each tupple?

Comment: Set building notation is { x : P(x) } for the set of all x such that P(x) where P is some statement about x which could be a conjunction of statements about x.

Comment: If it appears in a tuple, then it appears exactly once in that tuple. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: How can you create tuples from the set building notation? That part is still unclear to me.

Comment: (x,y) = { {x}, {x,y} };  (x,y,z)  = ((x,y),z);  etc.

Comment: In each tuple t appears at most once, ie. zero or one time.  E! means exactly once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have it.

Say $K=\{ 0, t, 1 \}$ is the set of possible values in these tuples. Then, $K^n$ is the set of $K$-valued $n$-tuples.

If I understand your question correctly, you asked for set of tuples containing $t$ exactly once:
$$ S = \{ a\in K^n \mid \exists! i \text{ such } 1\le i \le n \text{ and } a_i = t \}. $$
(It is pretty valid to use normal English in the condition part after $\mid$.)

Comment: If one was to add multiple conditions besides the one given in the example, is there a nice way to do this? That notation clarified the confusion I had. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Trotter the usual logical connectives are “and” ($\land$), “or” ($\lor$) and sometimes “implication” ($\implies$), and “equivalence” ($\iff$). You can also build different sets for different conditions and connect them by set operations, which are essential the same.